# python regarding dictionaries: user input replaces an item in the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace, user-input

How can I automatically replace blue with whatever the user inputted as their favorite color? Thanks in advance - my apologies for how this is such a beginner question.

```
def rainbow_colors():

    my_rainbow = ['#1:red', '#2:orange','#3:yellow','#4:green','#5:blue','#6:indigo','#7:violet']

    item = input('Please enter your favorite color:')
    print(my_rainbow)
    rainbow_colors()

rainbow_colors()
```

Comment: Totally unclear. What is your expected behavior? Once you clarified that, I'm sure the answer will be in any python tutorial. A bit of effort before posting please.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
def rainbow_colors():

    my_rainbow = ['#1:red','#2:orange','#3:yellow','#4:green','#5:blue','#6:indigo','#7:violet']

    item = input('Please enter your favorite color:')

    res = [x.replace('blue', item) for x in my_rainbow]

    return res

rainbow_colors()

# Please enter your favorite color:purple
# ['#1:red',
#  '#2:orange',
#  '#3:yellow',
#  '#4:green',
#  '#5:purple',
#  '#6:indigo',
#  '#7:violet']
```

**Explanation**

- Have your function `return` a value, *not* `print`.
- Don't call your function within the function. This makes it recursive and is not what you want.
- This solution uses a *list comprehension* to replace every occurrence of the string "blue" with the string that is input.
- Consider using `dict` (dictionary) to store a numbered sequence of items, using integers as keys.